# How to Retrieve Windows Night Light Sunset and Sunrise Times?

Tags: json, windows, server

### How to Get Windows Night Light Sunset and Sunrise Times Programmatically?

#### Question:

I want to know the sunset and sunrise times for Windows Night Light, which is a feature that adjusts the color temperature of the screen according to the time of day. However, I cannot find any Microsoft API that provides this information. Does anyone know how to get this data programmatically? I would appreciate any guidance or code examples on this topic.

I attempted to find a Microsoft API for this task but was unsuccessful.
I conducted a search for an answer, but I couldn't locate any information on the times or how to retrieve them on this Stack Overflow post: [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58205092/how-is-windows-10-night-light-implemented)

Comment: There is no API. You can [calculate it yourself](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sunrise_equation).